# Logo is not gradient in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I am new to WebDev and have been following a youtube tutorial for creating a website. However, I am stuck at this part. I cannot get my Logo to be gradient in Chrome.

```
#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199, 100%);
  background-size: 100;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code (including the HTML so we can debug the issue) to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code (plus a relevant element) using your browser's dev tools inspect facility you will see a  yellow triangle or something similar beside both the background-image and background-size properties.

The background image has a spurious comma.

The background-size is not needed in this case - but if you did need it you'd have to give it units.

```css
#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar__logo">LOGO</div>
```